# stsadm command to take backup of workspace

Tags: stsadm

I want to take backup of sharepoint workspace.
Please let me know the stsadm command for the same.

Url is : abc/xyz

where xyz is workspace created in site collection

stsadm –o backup –url " "  -filename D:\Backups   is not working

its not trowing error but backup is not being created.

Answer (score 2):

plz try with this

Export and import a subsite, list, or library:

**stsadm -o export –url [url of subsite, list, library] –filename D:\spbackup\backup.bak -quiet -overwrite**

**stsadm -o import –url [url of subsite, list, library] –filename D:\spbackup\backup.bak -quiet**

If the command is entered correctly and you have the permission needed to run the export, you should see the Operation Completed Successfully message when the export completes.
Move the newly created backup file to the destination server. To import the file to create new site enter the stsadm import command as shown in the example.

Hope it helps